# Do i have to always carry *.pem file to log in my AWS server in other computer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, putty

I have a EC2 server (UBUNTU).
I have a macbook and my ".pem" file is in my laptop computer.
When i try to log in my server through putty in other computer, it require my ".pem" file.
Do i have to store it in extra hard drive and carry it everytime?
Is there any the other way to access my server in other computer no matter which OS i used?

Answer (score 8):

## Do you have to?

No

## Should you?

Yes

## Why Private Keys?

You can configure SSH access a number of different ways.

private/public key pair is a common (and SECURE) method for Linux servers and the default method for Ubuntu AMIs.

## Where can you store your private key?

You can store your private key in a secure location (a shared disk or USB might work if you can ensure good physical security to the device...you will also want to consider encrypting the disk and/or putting a pass phrase on your private key).

You can also use multiple private keys for different devices. If one of your keys gets compromised you only need to replace that one, and the others are okay.

## Alternatives

Once you gain access to your server you can configure all sorts of access (like passwords instead a of keys, which I can't discourage enough).

You can look into locking down access to SSH to certain IPs, using two factor authentication and various other things, however private/public key pairs are common place and highly recommended.

Comment: I'm sorry but i cant understand what you meam.(I'm not good at english)

This is what i did.

At first, i log in my aws typing below in command
-->ssh -i otkey.pem rightx2@ec2-54-64-31-221.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

And in my server, i added my new account by 'adduser'(new account name is rightx2)
and open sshd_config file, set passward_authentication 'yes'.
then, restart ssh.

Comment: i quit the Terminal and start Terminal again. 
I tried to log in without 'pem' key. so i type below.
ssh rightx2@ ec2-54-64-31-221.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
but error occured : ssh: connect to host ec2-54-64-31-221.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused

Comment: When i typed like below,
ssh -v rightx2@ec2-54-64-31-221.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

error occur like this : OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-64-31-221.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [54.64.31.221] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 54.64.31.221 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ec2-54-64-31-221.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused

Comment: Don't use passwords for ssh it's not secure

Comment: Then always keep pem file with me? using usb?

Comment: Passwords are not _intrinsically_ insecure on ssh, provided you use one that is long and complex enough; passwords are not exchanged in the clear so you are still logging in over a secure channel. In principle they are less secure than using keys, but the main objection is that no one is going to remember (or want to key in) a password long enough to guarantee security. Using key pairs makes it trivial to maximise security and minimise hassle.

Comment: @DrewKhoury or ianjs could you elaborate on the advantages of keys over passwords? Like what's the fundamental difference? Isn't a key just a long password?

Comment: SSH keys are generally more secure than passwords. They use cryptographic techniques and are much longer than typical passwords, making them extremely difficult to crack through brute force attacks. SSH keys are not vulnerable to common password-related attacks such as dictionary attacks or password guessing. Since SSH keys do not involve remembering and typing in a password, they are immune to phishing attacks that trick users into revealing their passwords. SSH keys work on a public/private key mechanism. The public key can be shared freely, while the private key remains secure.